# React 16.11 componentDidMount infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-lifecycle

We have upgraded from react 16.9 to 6.11, and now we have infinite loop when side effect in componentDidMount.

```
export class DataComponent extends PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setData({id: 'new'});
    }
    render() {
        return <Text>{this.props.data.id}</Text>
    }
}

const mamStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.data
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setData: (data) => dispatch(setDataAction(data));
});

const DataContainer = connect(mamStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DataComponent);
```

The code is totally simple. But when it is mounting componentDidMount calling in loop until maximum call stack. 
Any ideas?

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
```

Comment: Can you post usage of `DataComponent` in your code? It's most likely how you use it.

Comment: Yes, It seems like something happen in other place. The project is big, and I can't find a place, where it can be... Strange than this started when we upgraded react

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setData({id: 'new'}); //add .props
}
```